# Decompose a list of integers into lists of increasing sequences

Tags: python

Assume no consecutive integers are in the list.

I've tried using NumPy (`np.diff`) for the difference between each element, but haven't been able to use that to achieve the answer. Two examples of the input (first line) and expected output (second line) are below.

```
[6, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6]
[[6], [0, 4, 8], [7], [6]]


[1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0]
[[1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 5], [4], [0]]
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: @NiklasNoem I think that's the opposite of what OP is looking for

Comment: No. Completely different questions.

Comment: You should include what you've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to enable iteration over sequential element pairs in your list along with `enumerate` to keep track of index values where the sequences are not increasing in order to append corresponding slices to your output list.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

nums = [1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0]

results = []
start = 0
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip_longest(nums, nums[1:])):
    if b is None or b <= a:
        results.append(nums[start:i+1])
        start = i + 1

print(results)
# [[1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 5], [4], [0]]
```

Comment: this is the most pythonic way and better than my approach!

Comment: This doesn't work in the case there's a 0 in the input list. `not b` should be `b is None`

Comment: @alexbclay - thanks for pointing that out. Answer edited accordingly (now properly handles inclusion of negative numbers if needed).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way to do what you're asking without any extra libraries:

```
result_list = []
sublist = []
previous_number = None

for current_number in inp:
    if previous_number is None or current_number > previous_number:
        # still ascending, add to the current sublist
        sublist.append(current_number)
    else:
        # no longer ascending, add the current sublist 
        result_list.append(sublist)

        # start a new sublist
        sublist = [current_number]
    previous_number = current_number
if sublist:
    # add the last sublist, if there's anything there
    result_list.append(sublist)
```

Comment: This will throw a `TypeError` immediately because you cannot compare `None` with an `int`

Comment: It doesn't throw a TypeError for me when I run this in either python 2 or 3

Comment: My bad, I had a bad test case.  This runs in python2.  I will update

Comment: If you edit so it works, for sure I'll remove the down :)

Comment: Updated.  My answer saves one pass through the array, instead of using `min()` to get the min value.

Comment: from a down to an up! Nice and clean

Comment: Thanks!  All these solutions are basically identical.

Comment: Careful, wont work with negative numbers. inp = [-6, 0, 4, -8, 7, 6]
result: [[-6, 0, 4, -8, 7, 6]]

Comment: How do you figure that?

Comment: I copied your function and ran it :)

Comment: Weird.  I get `[[-6, 0, 4], [-8, 7], [6]]` when I run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

Just cause I feel kind, this will also work with negative numbers.

```
seq = [6, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6]
seq_by_incr_groups = []  # Will hold the result
incr_seq = []  # Needed to create groups of increasing values.
previous_value = 0  # Needed to assert whether or not it's an increasing value. 
for curr_value in seq: # Iterate over the list
    if curr_value > previous_value: # It's an increasing value and belongs to the group of increasing values.
        incr_seq.append(curr_value)
    else:  # It was lower, lets append the previous group of increasing values to the result and reset the group so that we can create a new one.
        if incr_seq:  # It could be that it's empty, in the case that the first number in the input list is a negative.
            seq_by_incr_groups.append(incr_seq)
        incr_seq = []
        incr_seq.append(curr_value)
    previous_value = curr_value # Needed so that we in the next iteration can assert that the value is increasing compared to the prior one.

if incr_seq:  # Check if we have to add any more increasing number groups.
    seq_by_incr_groups.append(incr_seq)  # Add them.

print(seq_by_incr_groups)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering myself if I should write any answer as I was sure one would come anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Below code should help you. However I would recommend that you use proper nomenclature and consider handling corner cases:

```
li1 = [6, 0, 4, 8, 7, 6]
li2 = [1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0]

def inc_seq(li1):
  lix = []
  li_t = [] 
  for i in range(len(li1)):
    #print (i)
    if i < (len(li1) - 1) and li1[i] >= li1[i + 1]:
      li_t.append(li1[i])
      lix.append(li_t)
      li_t = []
    else:
      li_t.append(li1[i])


  print (lix)

inc_seq(li1)
inc_seq(li2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple `script` and you don't need `numpy` as far as I have understood your problem statement. Try the `script` below. I have tested it using `Python 3.6.7` and `Python 2.7.15+` on my Ubuntu machine.

```
def breakIntoList(inp):
    if not inp:
        return []

    sublist = [inp[0]]
    output = []
    for a in inp[1:]:
        if a > sublist[-1]:
            sublist.append(a)
        else:
            output.append(sublist);
            sublist = [a]


    output.append(sublist)
    return output



list = [1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0]
print(list)
print(breakIntoList(list))
```

**Explanation:**

1. The script first checks if input List passed to it has one or more elements.
2. It then initialise a sublist (`variable name`) to hold elements in increasing order. After that, we append input List's first element into our sublist.
3. We iterate through the input List beginning from it's second element (`Index: 1`). We keep on checking if the current element in Input List is greater than last element of sublist (by `sublist[-1]`). If yes, we append the current element to our sublist (at the end). If not, it means we can't hold that current element in sub-List. We append the sublist to output List and clear the sublist (for holding other increasing order sublists) and add the current element to our sublist.
4. At the end, we append the remaining sublist to the output List.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using dict, list comprehensions, and zip:

```
seq = [1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 0]
dict_seq = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(seq)}

# Get the index where numbers start to decrease
idx = [0] # Adding a zero seems counter-intuitive now; we'll see the benefit later.
for k, v in dict_seq.items():
    if k>0:
        if dict_seq[k]<dict_seq[k-1]:
            idx.append(k)

# Using zip, slice and handling the last entry
inc_seq = [seq[i:j] for i, j in zip(idx, idx[1:])] + [seq[idx[-1:]]]
```

Output

```
print(inc_seq)
>>> [[1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 5], [4], [0]]
```

By initiating `idx = [0]` and creating 2 sublists `idx`, `idx[1:]`, we can `zip` these sublists to form `[0:2], [2:5], [5:7] and [7:8]` with the list comprehension.

```
>>> print(idx)
>>> [0, 2, 5, 7, 8]

>>> for i, j in zip(idx, idx[1:]):
       print('[{}:{}]'.format(i,j))

[0:2]
[2:5]
[5:7]
[7:8]   # <-- need to add the last slide [8:]
```